# Who do I hire to install a dormer in a roof?

Tags: framing, roof, dormer, australia

I want to install a dormer in my attic in order to create more headroom and open it up.

This is well beyond my DIY skills, so I want to engage a trade.

Should I be looking for an engineer, a draftsman, an architect, a roofer or a carpenter?

Built 2001. Double brick construction. 4 bedrooms. Symmetrical metal pitched roof with pine engineered roof trusses. Roof pitch 30 degrees (I think).

Attic free of truss timbers and currently used as a teenagers retreat / games room. Attic max ceiling height 2.6 metres. Attic width ~8m. Length 12 metres. 10 acre rural block with no neighbours. Fixed staircase to attic already exists.

Jervis Bay, NSW Australia.

Comment: Should we assume the attic is finished?

Comment: You haven't really told us enough about your home for us to answer. Whether it was built in 1940 or 1990 matters, as well as its construction type and your geographic location.

Comment: Built 2001. Double brick construction. 4 bedrooms. Metal pitched roof with pine engineered roof trusses. Attick free of truss timbers. Attiic max ceiling height 2.4metres. 10 acre rural block with no neighbours. Jervis Bay, NSW Australia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call a contractor who does carpentry. Regardless of whether you'll need a licensed designer (an engineer or some architects), a contractor can let you know the costs involved. You don't want to invest in a completed set of drawings only to discover that the project isn't worth it after all.

You're proposing to remove a large chunk of roof diaphragm, so I expect localities with significant earthquake risk will require a licensed designer. Out West in my locality (with lower earthquake risk, i.e. Seismic Design Category C), your scope is commonly permitted without design documents stamped by a licensed designer. For Seismic Design Categories D and E, I expect that you'll need stamped design documents. [IRC R301.2.2.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch03_SecR301.2.2.1) has maps for looking up your Seismic Design Category.